# Electron Screen disappears from desktopcapture sources when launching fullscreen application

Tags: javascript, electron, screen-capture, recording

We are trying to use Electrons desktop capture to record som gameplay, but when I launch e.g: Rocket league in fullscreen mode, the screen it launches on disappears from the desktopcapture sources list.
This does not happen when i launch it in windowed-fullscreen.

We are two people working on this codebase and this is an issue only for me, it works fine for my colleague.

example of what's happening:

I set the system up to record "screen 1".

the system records screen 1 fine.

launch a fullscreen application When the application is running the recording shifts to record "screen 2".

We are not touching the selected source at any point during this time, so it almost seems like "screen 2" is "overwriting" / overtaking screen 1.

Have anyone experienced anything similar and found a solution?